# Изменить значение переменной по событию

Tags: jquery, javascript, переменные

Подскажите пожалуйста! Есть функция одной галереи вида:

```
$(function() {

    Gallery             = (function() {
            // index of the current item
        var current         = 0,
            // mode : carousel || fullview
            mode            = 'carousel',
            // control if one image is being loaded
            anim            = false,

            init            = function() {

                // (not necessary) preloading the images here...
                $items.add('<img src="/public/images/ajax-loader.gif"/><img src="/public/images/black.png"/>').imagesLoaded( function() {
                    // add options
                    _addViewModes();

                    // add large image wrapper
                    _addImageWrapper();

                    // show first image
                    _showImage( $items.eq( current ) );
                });

                // initialize the carousel
                _initCarousel();

            };

        return { init : init};

    })();

    Gallery.init();

});
```

Мне нужно изменить значение переменной current по событию onClick(), что бы значение было изменено до инициализации галереи. Заранее спасибо!

Upd1: Еще очень интересует как правильно называется в данном случае Gallery и как можно к таким штукам обращаться из вне данной функции и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Никто что ли не в курсе как такое сделать можно?

Comment: переменная var current объявлена внутри функции, потому изменить её можно только из функции, что бы она была доступна глобально объявите её до функции, а внутри уберите var.
 хотя может вам нужно просто инициализировать галерею после онклик, не ясно

Comment: Собственно все верно. Объявил переменную глобально, потом по onClick изменил ее значение, а из функции убрал как ее объявление, так и присвоение значения. Теперь остался вопрос: как инициализировать ее после onClick?